# Convert Chinese numeric characters to numbers in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am writing a Python function to convert numbers represented in a mix of Chinese and Arabic numbers to a numerical value.

```
import re

units = ['', '十', '百', '千', '萬', '十萬', '百萬', '千萬', '億', '十億', '百億', '千億']
# the Chinese means '', '100', '1000', '10000', etc.

def chinese_numeral_replace(input_text):
    if input_text.group(0) in units:
        idx = units.index(input_text.group(0))
        return '*' + str(pow(10, idx))
    else:
        return input_text

test2 = '5萬' # means 50 thousands or 50000
result = re.sub('|'.join(units).lstrip('|'), chinese_numeral_replace, test2)
print(eval(result))
```

which results `50000`. The value is `50*1000` which will then `eval()` to 50000.

The above function and codes work when the sentence is simple. However, if the input string is more complex like '5千萬5千' (which translates to 50000 + 5000, that's 55000), the above function will result in incorrect values.

I know there are 2 bugs:

1. The `re.sub()` returns incorrect results. For 千萬 in the complex case, the `re.sub()` will return 2 match groups ('千' and '萬') instead of '千萬' which is also in the `units` list.
2. The `chinese_numeral_replace` function hard codes `.group(0)` into the function, how can I ask the replace function to replace:

- 千萬 -> 10000000 (which means 10 million in Chinese, which 千 = 1000, 萬 = 10000)
- 千 -> 1000 (which means 1000 in Chinese)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `idx = units.index(test)` causes an exception.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to replace the variable. Fixed in question.

Comment: It looks as if the `+` is implied here, but how do you know where it should be added? When there is a unit word followed by a digit? What about float values? Are you only working with integers?

Comment: Yes, I assume the string does not contain decimal places, like 5.5萬. And yes, `+` sign is required to be added to concatenate two parts in the complex version.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know Chinese, but according to what you said, `5千萬5千` must be `50005000`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned, I'd always try and avoid eval unless absolutely necessary. I think I covered all the edge cases, but with no error handling.

```
import re

units = ['十', '百', '千', '萬', '十萬', '百萬', '千萬', '億', '十億', '百億', '千億']
unit_factors = {unit: 10**factor for factor, unit in enumerate(units, start=1)}
digit_unit_regex = re.compile(rf"(\d*)({'|'.join(reversed(units))})")


def chinese_numeral_replace(input_text: str) -> int:
    digit_unit_pairs = digit_unit_regex.findall(input_text)
    if not digit_unit_pairs:
        return int(input_text)
    return sum(replace_match(*m) for m in digit_unit_pairs)


def replace_match(digit_str: str, unit_str: str) -> int:
    digits = int(digit_str or 1)
    unit = unit_factors.get(unit_str, 1)
    return digits * unit


for test_string, expected in (('5', 5), ('萬', 10_000), ('5萬', 50_000), ('51萬', 510_000), ('5千萬', 50_000_000), ('5千萬萬', 50_010_000), ('5千萬5萬', 50_050_000)):
    result = chinese_numeral_replace(test_string)
    print(test_string, expected, result)
    assert result == expected
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of replacing and using `eval`, here's a safer approach: `re.sub` takes a function argument, where this function receives the `Match` object as its argument, and returns the replacement text. In this function, you can find the index of the "units" character(s) in the `units` list, and infer the power of 10 from that index.

```
import re

units = ['十', '百', '千', '萬', '十萬', '百萬', '千萬', '億', '十億', '百億', '千億']
# the Chinese means '10', '100', '1000', '10000', etc.

number_regex = re.compile(rf"(\d*)({'|'.join(reversed(units))})")
# '(\\d+)(千億|百億|十億|億|千萬|百萬|十萬|萬|千|百|十)'


def chinese_numeral_repl(match):
    num, multiplier = match.groups()
    power_of_10 = units.index(multiplier) + 1
    repl_value = int(num or 1) * 10**power_of_10
    return f"{repl_value:.0f}"

print(number_regex.sub(chinese_numeral_repl, '5千萬')) # 50000000
print(number_regex.sub(chinese_numeral_repl, '5萬')) # 50000
print(number_regex.sub(chinese_numeral_repl, '5千')) # 5000
```

Note the `re.compile` call includes `'|'.join(reversed(units))`.
Reversing the `units` list before joining it prioritizes the larger multipliers, so it looks for `'十億'` before looking for `'十'`. Keeping this in mind, maybe *sorting* by `len` would be a better strategy.

```
number_regex = re.compile(rf"(\d*)({'|'.join(sorted(units, key=len, reverse=True))})")
# '(\\d+)(十萬|百萬|千萬|十億|百億|千億|十|百|千|萬|億)'
```

---

For the "complex" version, you could extend this regex to match multiple instances of a number followed by an element of `units`. When processing this matched string, we can process each "piece" individually, sum them, and return the formatted number.

```
single_number_regex = rf"(\d*)({'|'.join(sorted(units, key=len, reverse=True))})"

full_number_regex = f"(?:{single_number_regex})+"

def single_numeral_eval(match):
    num, multiplier = match.groups()
    power_of_10 = units.index(multiplier) + 1
    return int(num or 1) * 10**power_of_10

def chinese_numeral_repl(match):
    full_number = sum(single_numeral_eval(m) for m in re.finditer(single_number_regex, match.group()))
    return f"{full_number:.0f}"

print(re.sub(full_number_regex, chinese_numeral_repl, '5千萬5千')) # 50005000
```

The difference between this approach and the other answer is that this approach will replace strings in-place, so you could do e.g.:

```
s = "5千萬 plus 5千 equals 5千萬5千"
print(re.sub(full_number_regex, chinese_numeral_repl, s))
# 50000000 plus 5000 equals 50005000
```

Comment: It returns: `TypeError: finditer() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'`

Comment: @Raptor my apologies, I forgot to update that part of the code after I tested and debugged it. I have made the update and verified it now.

Answer (score 0):

Please correct values in dictionary.

```py
units = {'': 1,
         '十': 10,
         '百': 100,
         '千': 1000,
         '萬': 10000,
         '十萬': 100000,
         '百萬': 1000000,
         '千萬': 10000000,
         '億'  : 100000000,
         '十億': 1000000000,
         '百億': 10000000000,
         '千億': 100000000000
         }

test2 = '6百億5萬'
print(sum([int(i[0]) * units[i[1]] for i in re.findall(r'(\d+)([^\d]*)', test2)]))
```

Comment: IT won't work if there are two more digits in the number. And it is using a regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it indeed uses regex. I'm sorry if I missed request not to use it. As for two digits, since there is a symbol for tens, I assumed that it is impossible.

Comment: Yes, my bad, I just noticed the regex, and it's okay to use Regex. But yes, if the string is something like  `56萬`, the answer is incorrect. oops.